# Configure udev to change permissions on USB HID device?

Tags: usb, input-devices, udev

I have a USB scale, a USB HID.  Currently, when it is plugged in, the permissions only allow the superuser to access it.  How can I configure udev to let anybody access this device?  I have the vendor and product IDs, but I would like to match it based on the HID type instead.

Right now, I'm having trouble finding any existing rule that applies to this (I grepped for "hidraw" in `/lib/udev/rules.d` and `/etc/udev/rules.d`, among other things).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Normally, this is done by adding to `/etc/udev/rules.d` a file maybe named `50-usb-scale.conf` with contents like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="HEX1", ATTR{idProduct}=="HEX2", MODE="0666"
```

Where **HEX1** and **HEX2** are replaced with the vendor and product id respectively.

To match on the Interface type instead, you could try replacing `ATTR{idVendor}=="HEX1", ATTR{idProduct}=="HEX2"` with a match for `bInterfaceClass` being `03` (HID):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="03", MODE="0666"
```

But be warned, that will catch mice and keyboards too.

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04 you have to use MODE:="0666", without the colon, the rule does nothing.

Comment: On 14.04 this file has to have a `.rules` extension. A file with a `.conf` extension won't work.

Comment: use `lsusb -vvv` to get the idProduct and idVendor

Comment: Since this question is quite popular in google output... I think it should be ATTRS, not ATTR - at least this change fixed it for me.

Comment: On 14.04.5 LTS I found: `lsusb` is a good start to see what's connected and IDs. `idVendor` and `idProduct` matches seem *case-sensitive*, so ID `DA77` doesn't work for me but `da77` does. (Handy diagnostic:  `udevadm info --attribute-walk /dev/bus/usb/008/023`, bus 008 device 023 my example; `lsusb` for yours.) After adding a rule, `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` and then `sudo udevadm trigger` avoids reboot: changes are seconds *after* that. ATTR vs ATTRS made no odds. My .rules file reads: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="da77", ATTR{idProduct}=="d12e", GROUP="users", MODE="0666"`.

Comment: On 16.04 LTS, `ATTR` works fine (another poster said to use ATTRS) and I did not need a colon after MODE.  This was for a delcom led: `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fc5", ATTR{idProduct}=="b080", MODE="0666"`

Answer (score 10):

Just for the summary:

You may filter for:

- idVendor
- idProduct
- serial

And use:

== Compare for equality.

!= Compare for inequality.

=  Assign a value to a key. Keys that represent a list are reset and only this single value is assigned.

+= Add the value to a key that holds a list of entries.

:= Assign a value to a key finally; disallow any later changes.

You may give a specific device a specific new path in /dev/...

Example:

```
KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="05df", ATTRS{serial}=="1234567", GROUP="cdrom", OWNER="user28", MODE="0640", SYMLINK+="myhid"
```

Results in:

You can access the device via '/dev/hiddevx' or via '/dev/myhid' easyly, every user in group 'cdrom' may read from the device. Owner 'user28' may read and write.

or simplest:

```
KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", MODE="0666"
```

Results in:
Every user may access every hiddevice from Vendor 0x16c0

For details see: [Docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev/udev.html)

Comment: `:=` is not for comparisons. [Docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#:=) say  "Assign a value to a key finally; disallow any later changes."

Answer (score 8):

In case you need to change (like me) `ttyACM0` permissions,
this are my settings:

```
KERNEL=="ttyACM0", MODE="0777"
```

It failed when I tried to specify the vendor and product ID. I am not sure why.

Comment: Yeah, the Kernel option works for most HID devices, better than the USB subsystem one

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 18.04 update/clarification:

Kees Cook's answer is close but requires 2 changes to work in 18.04 (the current release and only one I've tested this on).

1. Find your idVendor and idProduct with **lsusb**.

   - This will be the 2 hex values after "ID", separated by a colon.  I'm adding a scanner.  lsusb gave me:

     ```
     Bus 001 Device 011: ID 04b8:014a Seiko Epson Corp.
     ```
2. As **root** add a file to **/etc/udev/rules.d**

   - Something like **50-usb-epsonscanner.rules**
   - The extension must be ".rules"
3. In that file add:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTR{idProduct}=="014a", MODE="0666"
   ```

   But with your idVendor and idProduct hex values.

   - Note it's  "ATTRS" not "ATTR".
4. Re-login.  No need to reboot.

Comment: `ATTRS` both for vendor and product ID? Then your code sample is wrong (just as you state two lines later).

Comment: Just the second one is ATTR.  Works here.  Am guessing it's an error that could change without warning.

Comment: I think what's happening is that the second one is just getting ignored.  So it seems to work because you don't have a second device with the same vendor ID.

Answer (score 3):

If its a HIDRAW device, you have to

```
chmod 0666 /dev/hidrawX
```

where X is the hid device number, e.g hidraw0. you can do

```
ls /dev/hid*
```

to see a list :)
Or just do

```
sudo chmod 0666 /dev/hidraw*
```

to set for all hidraw devices, probably not recommended.

Comment: That gets the job done as a quick hack, but the setting won't persist across a reboot or even hot-plugging the device.  The UDEV rule is the way to go if you want your settings to persist.

Answer (score 2):

For a USB tty device, I needed to do:

`SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", MODE="0666", GROUP="bkg"`

The accepted answer was good - but needed the `SUBSYSTEM` to be `tty`

The thing that helped be debug, was to be able to see what UDEV was doing by doing a:

`udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)`

Comment: Solved my problem after several days of frustration, thank you!  There was nothing at all to show that my USB deice was being used in tty mode, but I tried it and it worked!