# How to permanently chmod a+w to usb scanner?

Tags: permissions, scanner, sane, xsane

chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/xxx/xxx    allows  *simple-scan* or *iscan* to work, but each time the scanner is turned on it claims a new bus:devnum

How can I get the scanner to use the same bus:devnum each time?  Or is there a better way?

---

There's lots of posts about scanners not working.  Eventually most of them seem to land on the permissions issue.  I haven't been able to find something that will work more than this manual tweak each time the scanner is turned on.

As many others have noted, adding saned to scanner, or even (!) to root did not help.

**The 'manual' solution:**
Find the bus:devnum of your scanner, chmod it.

```
lsusb
sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/xxx/xxx
```

Example:

```
> lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c080 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04b8:014a Seiko Epson Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 17ef:6047 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0b05:185c ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0b05:1872 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> 
> sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/001/003
[sudo] password for gato: 
>
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I think this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/15570/configure-udev-to-change-permissions-on-usb-hid-device has exactly the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In a number of cases I have seen using gscan2pdf from the Ubuntu Software Centre works more intuitively than simple scan and others.